# Rename a file during install of a Debian package

Tags: python, packaging, debian

I have a python script that I want to package for Debian. I use a debian/install file where I wrote

```
auto_dice.py /usr/bin/
```

Linitan then complains about the .py extension (script-with-language-extension).

I then changed it to

```
auto_dice.py /usr/bin/autodice.py
```

which causes an error because it interpreted `autodice.py` as a directory.

How can I do the rename there? I do not want to rename my python script in the sources.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You cannot rename files using `dh_install` (via the `debian/install`). You will need to rename it during the `debian/rules` "build" target before you get to the `dh_install` invocation.

Comment: so it will be `build: \\ mv auto_dice.py autodice`?

Comment: likely the mv would happen in the target directory rather than the build directory, but yeah, you'd have to add the move before calling dh_install.

Comment: For a bug report requesting this feature, see http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=245554

Comment: @Kees Cook: if you rename it in the target directory - would apt-get still be able to remove the file after package removal/upgrading?

Answer (score 15):

From [Debian bug 245554](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=245554) already mentioned:

> this can already be easily solved if you use dh >= 9
>   and dh-exec. Just make your .install file executable, 
>   add #!/usr/bin/dh-exec 
>   to the top, and you can use "source => dest", like
>   this:

```
#!/usr/bin/dh-exec
debian/default.conf => /etc/my-package/start.conf
```

Comment: This definitely is the best way. Not much to do really, just make sure you have `dh-exec` installed, enter the list of files to be installed with a different name, and also make sure that the `install` file is an executable (`chmod a+x`). Very easy!

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to specify that if the file to install is a folder, you can also rename it by using a pattern. This may not be self explanatory, so I thought it would be a good idea to have an example.

Say you have a configuration folder named `source` and you want to install it on target machines as `destination`. Your `.install` file would look like this:

```
path/to/source/*       path/to/destination/
```

This is rather simple, but you may not think about using the pattern when installing a whole folder.